# Leverage Bootstrap 5.3 color modes depending on browser's

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, darkmode

I understand Bootstrap 5.3 brings his [color scheme support](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/) and that I can customize the behavior of several main features.

Now it seems the built-in dark theme does not depend on `prefers-color-scheme: dark` and rather on the explicitely defined `bs-theme` data attribute. So browser's prefered theme is not taken into account.

Do I need to update `<html>`'s `data-bs-theme` with JS at page load and put it in the local storage for example ?

```
const lsBsTheme = localStorage.getItem("bs-theme")
const bsTheme = lsBsTheme ||
  window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches ? "dark" : "light"
document.querySelector("html").dataset.bsTheme = bsTheme
if (!lsBsTheme) localStorage.setItem("bs-theme", bsTheme)
```

Seems laborious. Isn't there any simpler ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only consider `prefers-color-scheme`, you can [build Bootstrap with Sass](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/#building-with-sass) and set the variable `$color-mode-type: media-query;`

If the user should also be able to toggle between light and dark and have their preference saved, using `localStorage` and data attributes would be appropriate (like shown in the question). There isn't any method built-in to the library. The Bootstrap documentation provides [sample code](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/#javascript) for this:

```js
/*!
 * Color mode toggler for Bootstrap's docs (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2023 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License.
 */

(() => {
  'use strict'

  const getStoredTheme = () => localStorage.getItem('theme')
  const setStoredTheme = theme => localStorage.setItem('theme', theme)

  const getPreferredTheme = () => {
    const storedTheme = getStoredTheme()
    if (storedTheme) {
      return storedTheme
    }

    return window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches ? 'dark' : 'light'
  }

  const setTheme = theme => {
    if (theme === 'auto' && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', 'dark')
    } else {
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', theme)
    }
  }

  setTheme(getPreferredTheme())

  const showActiveTheme = (theme, focus = false) => {
    const themeSwitcher = document.querySelector('#bd-theme')

    if (!themeSwitcher) {
      return
    }

    const themeSwitcherText = document.querySelector('#bd-theme-text')
    const activeThemeIcon = document.querySelector('.theme-icon-active use')
    const btnToActive = document.querySelector(`[data-bs-theme-value="${theme}"]`)
    const svgOfActiveBtn = btnToActive.querySelector('svg use').getAttribute('href')

    document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-theme-value]').forEach(element => {
      element.classList.remove('active')
      element.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'false')
    })

    btnToActive.classList.add('active')
    btnToActive.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'true')
    activeThemeIcon.setAttribute('href', svgOfActiveBtn)
    const themeSwitcherLabel = `${themeSwitcherText.textContent} (${btnToActive.dataset.bsThemeValue})`
    themeSwitcher.setAttribute('aria-label', themeSwitcherLabel)

    if (focus) {
      themeSwitcher.focus()
    }
  }

  window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', () => {
    const storedTheme = getStoredTheme()
    if (storedTheme !== 'light' && storedTheme !== 'dark') {
      setTheme(getPreferredTheme())
    }
  })

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    showActiveTheme(getPreferredTheme())

    document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-theme-value]')
      .forEach(toggle => {
        toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
          const theme = toggle.getAttribute('data-bs-theme-value')
          setStoredTheme(theme)
          setTheme(theme)
          showActiveTheme(theme, true)
        })
      })
  })
})()
```

Comment: Understood thanks ! I didn't see the `$color-mode-type` setting on the docs at first read. Now I understand better why this JS is needed.

Comment: Didn't get why this variable is not set to `media-query` by default though. Seems counter intuitive for me, since initial dark colors are supplied but not used.